# SQL Where Query to Return Distinct Values

Tags: sql, distinct, where-clause

I have an app that has the built in initial Select option and only allows me to enter from the Where section.  I have rows with duplicate values.  I'm trying to get the list of just one record for each distinct value but am unsure how to get the statement to work.  I've found one that almost does the trick but it doesn't give me any rows that had a dup.  I assume due to the = so just need a way to get one for each that matches my where criteria.  Examples below.

Initial Data Set

```
Date      | Name   | ANI         | CallIndex   | Duration
---------------------------------------------------------    
2/2/2015  | John   | 5555051000  | 00000.0001  | 60  
2/2/2015  | John   |             | 00000.0001  | 70 
3/1/2015  | Jim    | 5555051001  | 00000.0012  | 80  
3/4/2015  | Susan  |             | 00000.0022  | 90 
3/4/2015  | Susan  | 5555051002  | 00000.0022  | 30  
4/10/2015 | April  | 5555051003  | 00000.0030  | 35 
4/11/2015 | Leon   | 5555051004  | 00000.0035  | 10 
4/15/2015 | Jane   | 5555051005  | 00000.0050  | 20 
4/15/2015 | Jane   | 5555051005  | 00000.0050  | 60 
4/15/2015 | Kevin  | 5555051006  | 00000.0061  | 35
```

What I Want the Query to Return

```
Date      | Name   | ANI         | CallIndex   | Duration
---------------------------------------------------------    
2/2/2015  | John   | 5555051000  | 00000.0001  | 60
3/1/2015  | Jim    | 5555051001  | 00000.0012  | 80
3/4/2015  | Susan  | 5555051002  | 00000.0022  | 30
4/10/2015 | April  | 5555051003  | 00000.0030  | 35
4/11/2015 | Leon   | 5555051004  | 00000.0035  | 10
4/15/2015 | Jane   | 5555051005  | 00000.0050  | 20
4/15/2015 | Kevin  | 5555051006  | 00000.0061  | 35
```

Here is what I was able to get but when i run it I don't get the rows that did have dups callindex values.  duration doesn't mattern and they never match up so if it helps to query using that as a filter that would be fine.  I've added mock data to assist.

```
use Database
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Date between '4/15/15 00:00' and '4/15/15 23:59'
and callindex in
                (SELECT callindex 
                 FROM table 
                 GROUP BY callinex 
                 HAVING COUNT(callindex) = 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ok with the assistance of everyone here i was able to get the query to work perfectly within SQL.  That said apparently the app I'm trying this on has a built in character limit and the below query is too long.  This is the query i have to use as far as the restrictions and i have to be able to search both ID's at the same time because some get stamped with one or the other rarely both.  I'm hoping someone might be able to help me shorten it?

```
use Database
select * from tblCall
WHERE 
    flddate between '4/15/15 00:00' and '4/15/15 23:59'
    and fldAgentLoginID='1234'
    and fldcalldir='incoming'
    and fldcalltype='external'
    and EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(fldCallName) AS fldCallName, fldCallID FROM tblCall GROUP BY fldCallID) derv WHERE tblCall.fldCallName = derv.fldCallName AND tblCall.fldCallID = derv.fldCallID)
or
    flddate between '4/15/15 00:00' and '4/15/15 23:59'
    and '4/15/15 23:59'
    and fldPhoneLoginID='56789'
    and fldcalldir='incoming'
    and fldcalltype='external'
    and EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(fldCallName) AS fldCallName, fldCallID FROM tblCall GROUP BY fldCallID) derv WHERE tblCall.fldCallName = derv.fldCallName AND tblCall.fldCallID = derv.fldCallID)
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Is there a unique ID field in this table? Or just these four columns?

Comment: It's impossible with a simple in clause because no single column will help you, only a combination. You can only solve it with a JOIN or, most simply, with a group by statement like Ben Jasper's answer

Comment: I tagged it as SQL was there something more specific you needed?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the additional column you provided. Take a look and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two keywords you can use to get non-duplicated data, either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY`. In this case, I would use a `GROUP BY`, but you should read up on both.

This query groups all of the records by CallIndex and takes the `MAX` value for each of the other columns and should give you the results you want:

```
SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date, MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(ANI) AS ANI, CallIndex
FROM table
GROUP BY CallIndex
```

**EDIT**

Since you can't use `GROUP BY` directly but you can have any SQL in the `WHERE` clause you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT MAX(Date) AS Date, MAX(Name) AS Name, MAX(ANI) AS ANI, CallIndex
       FROM table
       GROUP BY CallIndex   
    ) derv
    WHERE table.Date = derv.Date 
         AND table.Name = derv.Name
         AND table.ANI = derv.ANI
         AND table.CallIndex = derv.CallIndex
)
```

This selects all rows from the table where there exists a matching row from the `GROUP BY`.

It won't be perfect, if any two rows match exactly, you'll still have duplicates, but that's the best you'll get with your restriction.

Comment: I'm not OP, but they made it seem like they could only alter the WHERE clause, not the SELECT or GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: I made the (rather unfair, I admit) assumption they just didn't have the SQL skills to ask the right question.

Comment: I do get the feeling that this could likely be handled best outside of the bounds that OP has put on the situation. Like pulling the data to excel, or accessing the data through different means or something. Otherwise the situation is kind of silly - trying to correct bad data with bad tools.

Comment: You are correct in that i don't have the SQL skills however in the question i did mean it when i said i could not control the initial select statement within the app because it's built in.  I start at the where.  Now a select within the where works which is why this line appears to work properly

fldcallid in
 (SELECT fldcallid FROM tblcall GROUP BY fldCallID HAVING COUNT(fldCallID)=1)

so is there a way to get it to show all distinct values from there or is Having and Group By the only functions that work at that point?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer to combine the GROUP BY with your restriction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your query.  It helped me get the results I needed within SQL.

Answer (score 2):

If the constraint is that we can only add to the WHERE clause, I don't think it's possible, due to there being 2 absolutely identical rows:

```
 4/15/2015 | Jane   | 5555051005  | 00000.0050    
 4/15/2015 | Jane   | 5555051005  | 00000.0050
```

Is it possible that you can add HAVING or GROUP BY to the WHERE?  or possibly UNION the SELECT to another SELECT statement?  That may open up some additional possibilities.

Comment: Yes i believe so because this Query works but doesn't include a record for the with the dup value.  I have a Duration field i can use as those are never the same if it would help to have two fields.

Answer (score 1):

From your sample, it seems like you could just exclude rows in which there was no value in the ANI column. If that is the case you could simply do:

```
use Database
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Date between '4/15/15 00:00' and '4/15/15 23:59'
and ANI is not null
```

If this doesn't work for you, let me know and I can see what else I can do.

Edit:
You've made it sound like the CallIndex combined with the Duration is a unique value. That seems somewhat doubtful to me, but if that is the case you could do something like this:

```
use Database
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Date between '4/15/15 00:00' and '4/15/15 23:59'
and cast(callindex as varchar(80))+'-'+cast(min(duration) as varchar(80)) in
                (SELECT cast(callindex as varchar(80))+'-'+cast(min(duration) as varchar(80)) 
                 FROM table 
                 GROUP BY callindex)
```

Comment: This looks OK to me given the limited example

Comment: Actually, as BranLakes points out, there are two rows that are complete duplicates with values in the ANI field. So it seems this solution won't work.

Comment: ahh yes... see that now.

Comment: Sadly no that would not work either because sometimes they'll have the same ANI value.  They do have a duration field that is never the same on the dups if that could help?  The database has about 50 columns so didn't want to put them all just using an example data set.

Comment: Yes, that would help. You should edit your question with more details, because in its current state it is not solvable using the method you've outlined.

Comment: Yes the problem is we have too entities entering in the data and i've tried to get our dev team to not double up on it.  the built in starts the transaction first which writes the callindex then the app stops that transaction and starts another that is the remainder of the call.  Both calls get stamped with the callindex value but one is shorter than the other.  The query you provided returns the below error when i run against our database.  Any thoughts?

The conversion of the varchar value '00001128351429100068-' overflowed an int column.

Comment: You'll have to explicitly convert to varchar. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with an union:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY Date, Name, ANI, CallIndex
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Name not in (SELECT name from table
GROUP BY Date, Name, ANI, CallIndex
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your data, why not just do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date >= '2015-04-15' and Date < '2015-04-16'
      ani is not null;
```

If the blank values are only a coincidence, then you have a problem just using a `where` clause.  If the results are full duplicates (*no* column has a different value), then you probably cannot do what you want with just a `where` clause -- unless you are using SQLite, Oracle, or Postgres.